# Можно ли в редакторе GDScript в godot упорядочить код чтобы не было лишних пробелов?

Tags: godot, gdscript

Из-за лишних пробелов возникает ошибка: Unexpected indentation
Если еще писать самому пол беды, но если копировать код то это какой то ужас, не в ручную же эти ошибки править.

Comment: Выделить проблемный кусок кода и жать Tab или Shift+Tab для отступа вправо или влево

Comment: Не ну это я знаю. Но если этого кода много это не вариант все в ручную

Comment: А кроме вас никто не может знать, где должны стоять отступы. Правильных вариантов отступов может быть несколько, и все они будут работать по-разному

Comment: И как вы на нем пишете, это ж какой то ужас и главное всех все устраивает. И это официальный язык.

Comment: Ну я когда на С# пишу в ide упорядочить функция есть.

Comment: У меня никогда не возникало ситуации, когда «много кода» имело неправильный отступ, никакого ужаса нет

Comment: Да ладно никогда копировать вставить не делали? Это вы обманываете. Но вообще спасибо за ответ, продолжу писать на C#  Я просто подумать не мог что вот так вот неудобно и все это терпят. Думал я что то не знаю. Я лично не смог из-за этого на Gd script писать.

Comment: Я не знаю, что за дичь вы творите, но у меня при копировании и вставке все отступы всегда сохраняются. Если же после вставки они смещены относительно нужного положения, то выдлелить вставленный кусок кода и пару раз нажать Tab или Shift+Tab для меня не проблема

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145669/discussion-between-madoka-magica-and-andreymal).